# Different behaviour between local notebook and Cloud deployed Manipulate function

Tags: manipulate, cloud-deploy

[image]

I've been happy with my development in the Wolfram Language but haven't played with deploying manipulatable content before. I've written a rather basic `Manipulate` function to let users explore changing chord lengths on a spline. It's working as expected in my local notebook. It initializes a random spline and then lets the user change the chord length, and if desired choose a new random spline. However, when I deploy the function to the cloud (it's actually composed of 7 functions with the main two viz functions listed below) it unforuately triggers new random spline whenever the slider is moved. It's slow and not the desired behaviour. I isolated the set of functions in a new notebook and still the behaviour persists. I think I'm missing something about how variables are different locally and deployed. Does anyone have any suggestions about how to correct this behaviour?

```
dynamicViz[controlpoints_, step_] := Module[{var, curve, results},
  curve = DiscretizeGraphics[BSplineCurve[controlpoints]];
  results = objectiveFunction[controlpoints, step];
  
  Graphics[{
    {Orange, AbsoluteThickness[3], MeshPrimitives[curve, 1]},
    {Red, AbsoluteThickness[5], Line@results[["points"]]},
    {Black, AbsolutePointSize[7], Point /@ results[["points"]]}
    },
   PlotLabel -> Style[
     "Chord Length: " <> ToString@step <>
      " | Error: " <> 
      ToString@Round[results[["error"]] , 0.1] <>
      " | Count: " <> 
      ToString@Length@(results[["points"]] - 1),
     20, FontFamily -> "Sans Source Pro"
     ],
   AspectRatio -> Automatic,
   ImageMargins -> 20,
   ImageSize -> 700,
   Frame -> True,
   GridLines -> Automatic
   ]
  ]

CloudDeploy[
 Manipulate[
  dynamicViz[pts, step], {{step, 2000, Style["Chord Length", 20]}, 300,
    4000, 20}, Button["New Spline", pts = control], 
  Initialization :> {pts = control}]
]
```

Currently this [deployed public version](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/cea89747-867e-4f67-a4be-acecdfa78946) is active as of Dec 18 2020 so one can see the behaviour.